# Designing footprint for LFCSP CP-8-13 what should be the pad size

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, altium, footprint

I am scratching my head to create a footprint for ADA4817 which comes in LFCSP CP-8-13 package. I reckon this package is only used by Analog Devices.

The main problem is I do not know what should be the pad size for the pins. The pins are stated to be 0.25mm in width and 0.40mm in height with a semi-circle ending:

[image]

So these are my concerns:

1. What should be the pad size be (copper) for each pin
2. What should be the glue size be (for stencil)
3. The copper shape should be a rectangle, or I should care for that round ending on the pads?
4. My other concern is the distance between pins and the exposed pad. Can I get away by making the exposed pad footprint smaller than the actual exposed pad size? e.g. going with a 1x1mm square instead of 1.4x1.4mm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there can be no general answer. The shape and size of pads depend on very many things, among these:

- Purpose, usually a mixture of the following, dominated by one purpose:

  - Thermal transfer
  - mechanical stability
  - high current capability
  - impedance matched high frequency signalling
- PCB fabrication tolerances
- Component placement tolerances
- thermal and mechanical aspects of the soldering process

So, if you're doing a board with a high-quality PCB manufacturer to be assembled by high-end pick and place machines and soldered with a well-calibrated reflow oven, then the pads will usually be minimally, if at all, wider than the pins, unless certain pads should be wider to allow for an all-around "solder taper" for more current or heat transfer capabilities.

If on the other you're sending this off to some unknown least-cost manufacturer and plan to assemble the board by hand, by all means, make the pads as wide as possible without risking solder bridges, and add a lot of exposed are outside the pad outline, where you can actively transfer heat into the solder paste.

Now, considering the free space between pins is but 0.25mm, I'd say: go for pads that are exactly as wide as your pins, and pray you get your manufacturing tolerances low enough!

Comment: Thanks for the insight :P my other concern is the distance between pins and the exposed pad. Can I get away by making the exposed pad footprint smaller than the actual exposed pad size? e.g. going with a 1x1mm square instead of 1.4x1.4mm?

Comment: @Sean87, probably, but the question really is whether you want to, considering it's used for thermal transfer.

Comment: For impedance matched signaling what kind of pad is suggested?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd You will need to read up on what impedance matching means if you think there's one answer to that question, regardless of the impedances involved.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Means to use microstrip or coplanar wave guide with specific intrinsic impedance?